# Better automated html meta tags with php

Tags: php, html, meta

I need to do this in a better way or maybe fix the error im encountered with.
Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\config.php on line 15

```
<?php
    $meta_build = "<head>";
    $meta = array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'title',
                    'content' => 'Test'
                ),

                array(
                    'type' => 'meta',
                    'name' => 'description',
                    'content' => 'Somestuff',
                ),

                array(
                    'type' => 'meta',
                    'name' => 'viewport',
                    'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no'
                ),

                array(
                    'type' => 'text/css',
                    'link' => 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web'
                ),

                array(
                    'type' => 'css',
                    'link' => '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                ),

                array(
                    'type' => 'css',
                    'link' => '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
                ),

                array(
                    'type' => 'css',
                    'link' => '/css/main.css'
                )

        );
    foreach($meta as $item){
        if($item['type'] == 'title'){
            $meta_build .= "<title>";
            $meta_build .= $item['content'];
            $meta_build .= "</title>";
        }

        if($item['type'] == 'meta'){
            $meta_build .= "<meta";
            $meta_build .= 'name="';
            $meta_build .= $item['name'].'" content="';
            $meta_build .= $item['content'].'"/>';
        }

        if($item['type'] == 'text/css'){
            $meta_build .= '<link rel="stylesheet"';
            $meta_build .= 'href="'.$item['link'].'"';
            $meta_build .= "type='text/css'/>";
        }

        if($item['type'] == 'css'){
            $meta_build .= '<link rel="stylesheet"';
            $meta_build .= 'href="'.$item['link'].'"/>';
        }

    }


    $meta_build .= "</head>";
    echo $meta_build;
?>
```

Comment: I executed your code and i got zero errors using php 5.4.4 and error_reporting(E_ALL).

Comment: May be you have to put spaces when construct the tags. Example: '<link rel="stylesheet"' should become '<link rel="stylesheet" '. This way next attribute will be on the right place

Comment: Also is the file you show called config.php?

Comment: Nope not helping. Maybe you can help me write a efficient way to construct my meta tags with php. No the file is called head.php. JESUS im blind ... or i can't read.

Answer (score 0):

if you modify your foreach like this you will have proper white spaces and a new line for each tag.

```
foreach($meta as $item){
    if($item['type'] == 'title'){
        $meta_build .= "<title>";
        $meta_build .= $item['content'];
        $meta_build .= "</title>";
    }

    else if($item['type'] == 'meta'){
        $meta_build .= "<meta ";
        $meta_build .= 'name="';
        $meta_build .= $item['name'].'" content="';
        $meta_build .= $item['content'].'"/>';
    }

    else if($item['type'] == 'text/css'){
        $meta_build .= '<link rel="stylesheet" ';
        $meta_build .= 'href="'.$item['link'].'" ';
        $meta_build .= "type='text/css'/>";
    }

    else if($item['type'] == 'css'){
        $meta_build .= '<link rel="stylesheet" ';
        $meta_build .= 'href="'.$item['link'].'"/>';
    }
    $meta_build .= "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank's Steven. Now it's working as i wanted. I didn't know about the "\n" thing.

Comment: @Urahara i talk about the added `\n`